# Cannot save inbox email items to local folder using ews vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Hello everyone i cannot save email inbox items to local folder. I want to save email items with the subject in the selected folder. I am using ews.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the emails in some sort of format E.G `.eml` format.

I'm not familiar with the VB syntax but the below C# should point you in the right direction:

```
message.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent));
var mimeContent = message.MimeContent;

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"P:\TestEmail1\Test.eml", FileMode.Create))
{
    fileStream.Write(mimeContent.Content, 0, mimeContent.Content.Length);
}
```

Comment: @Suja If this was the solution, please mark as answer.